# What happens to an open cursor after rolling back the transaction in Postgres using Psycopg2?

Tags: python, database, postgresql, cursor, psycopg2

I am trying to copy a list of **CSV** files into **Postgres** using **Psycopg2's** `copy_expert()`.

I'm opening cursor to execute copy command for each file separately and closing it after the data has been copied. 
But, If I get any error for any file in this process, I'm rolling back the transaction.

If I get an error I'm not sure what's going to happen to the cursor that I have opened before copying the **CSV** file.

Will it be closed automatically after the **rollback** is done on the connection or will it stay just like that?

I've checked the docs for rollback on **psycopg2** http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/connection.html#connection.rollback. But still, I'm unsure of what happens to the cursor that hasn't been closed as they haven't mentioned anything related to the cursor in the docs.

```
try:
    for tablename, filename in self.mapping:
        cur = self.conn.cursor()
        filename = f"{self.to_db}{wid}-{filename}"
        filename = f"{os.path.join(self.directory, filename)}.csv"
        sql = f"copy {tablename} from stdin with delimiter as ',' csv header;"
        with open(f"{filename}", 'r') as file:
            cur.copy_expert(sql, file)
        cur.close()
    self.conn.commit()
except Exception as e:
    self.conn.rollback()
    return e
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make use the cursor's context manager, when the code leaves the `with´-block, the cursor is closed automatically.
Since you are firing the commit after the for-loop, there is no need to 're-create' the cursor every loop iteration.

```
class foo():
    def __init__(self):
        self.conn = psycopg2.connect('host=...')

    def whatever(self):
        with self.conn.cursor() as cur:
            try:
                for tablename, filename in self.mapping:
                    filename = f"{self.to_db}{wid}-{filename}"
                    filename = f"{os.path.join(self.directory, filename)}.csv"
                    sql = f"copy {tablename} from stdin with delimiter as ',' csv header;"
                    with open(f"{filename}", 'r') as file:
                        cur.copy_expert(sql, file)
                self.conn.commit()
            except Exception as e:
                self.conn.rollback()
                return e
```